# How i show ViewBag value in my view page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have two class. Such as:

[image: VoterReg model]

[image: Candidate model]

My controller code is shown below:

```
 public class ResultController : Controller
{
    private OnlineVotingSystemEntities db = new OnlineVotingSystemEntities();
    // GET: Result
    public ActionResult result()
    {
        var vp = (from c in db.Candidates
                  join v in db.VoterRegs
                  on c.UserReg equals v.UserRegNo
                  where c.CandidatePosition == "VP"
                  orderby c.Vote descending
                  select  new {
                                               UserPhoto = v.UserPhoto,
                                               UserFirstName =v.UserFirstName,
                                               UserRegNo = v.UserRegNo,
                                               Vote = c.Vote
                         }).ToList();
    ViewBag.VP1 = vp;

        var gs = (from c in db.Candidates
                  join v in db.VoterRegs
                  on c.UserReg equals v.UserRegNo
                  where c.CandidatePosition == "GS"
                  orderby c.Vote descending
                  select new
                  {
                      UserPhoto = v.UserPhoto,
                      UserFirstName = v.UserFirstName,
                      UserRegNo = v.UserRegNo,
                      Vote = c.Vote
                  }).ToList();
        ViewBag.GS1 = gs ;

        var ags = (from c in db.Candidates
                   join v in db.VoterRegs
                   on c.UserReg equals v.UserRegNo
                   where c.CandidatePosition == "AGS"
                   orderby c.Vote descending
                   select new
                   {
                       UserPhoto = v.UserPhoto,
                       UserFirstName = v.UserFirstName,
                       UserRegNo = v.UserRegNo,
                       Vote = c.Vote
                   }).ToList();
        ViewBag.AGS1 = ags;

        var member = (from c in db.Candidates
                      join v in db.VoterRegs
                      on c.UserReg equals v.UserRegNo
                      where c.CandidatePosition == "Member"
                      orderby c.Vote descending
                      select new
                      {
                          UserPhoto = v.UserPhoto,
                          UserFirstName = v.UserFirstName,
                          UserRegNo = v.UserRegNo,
                          Vote = c.Vote
                      }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Member1 = member;
        return View();
    }
```

}

My View Page is shown below:

```html
@using OnlineVoting.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "result";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>result</h2>
   
<div class="container">
    <h4>VP</h4>

    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1" class="dataTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Registration Number</th>
            <th>Vote</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.VP1)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><p><img src="data:image;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.UserPhoto)" style="width:60px; height: 80px" class="VPimage" /></p></td>
                <td>@item.UserFirstName</td>
                <td>@item.UserRegNo</td>
                <td>@item.Vote</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <h4>GS</h4>

    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Registration Number</th>
            <th>Vote</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.GS1)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><p><img src="data:image;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.UserPhoto)" style="width:60px; height: 80px" class="VPimage" /></p></td>
                <td>@item.UserFirstName</td>
                <td>@item.UserRegNo</td>
                <td>@item.Vote</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h4>AGS</h4>

    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Registration Number</th>
            <th>Vote</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.AGS1)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><p><img src="data:image;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.UserPhoto)" style="width:60px; height: 80px" class="VPimage" /></p></td>
                <td>@item.UserFirstName</td>
                <td>@item.UserRegNo</td>
                <td>@item.Vote</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h4>MEMBER</h4>

    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Registration Number</th>
            @*<th>Vote</th>*@
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Member1)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><p><img src="data:image;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.UserPhoto)" style="width:60px; height: 80px" class="VPimage" /></p></td>
                <td>@item.UserFirstName</td>
                <td>@item.UserRegNo</td>
                <td>@item.Vote</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

When I run this code then show the output:

Image 3 show the output of this code. I got an error. This error is : object does not contain a definition for UserPhoto. Why I got this type of error? Please help me.

[image: Output]

Comment: Pass models to your view, not anonymous objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you are using anonymous object but I am suggesting to you to use strongly typed object and since you are using Viewbag, no need to cast in view. Like 
`

```
var vp = (from c in db.Candidates
              join v in db.VoterRegs
              on c.UserReg equals v.UserRegNo
              where c.CandidatePosition == "VP"
              orderby c.Vote descending
              select  new CandiateViewModel{
                                           UserPhoto = v.UserPhoto,
                                           UserFirstName =v.UserFirstName,
                                           UserRegNo = v.UserRegNo,
                                           Vote = c.Vote
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: How i declare candidateViewModel and where i declare ? I am new in MVC. So i need help. Please dono't mind for asking a question.

Comment: @Jishudas use the folllowing code <pre>                                                                   public class CandidateViewModel
{
    public string UserPhoto { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserRegNo { get; set; }
    public string Vote { get; set; }
}</pre>